# How can a JavaScript object be false and not null?

Tags: javascript, servicenow, rhino

From within a ServiceNow script, I am trying to detect whether or not something is defined.

On [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) it says

> All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy. That is, all values are truthy except false, 0, -0, 0n, "", null, undefined, and NaN.

Thus, any JavaScript object must be true unless it is null.

Yet consider this ServiceNow code which prints some information about an Incident that was created by a Record Producer which had a variable named `location`.

```
var incGR = new GlideRecord('incident');
incGR.get('49eab040975d6510378377500153afe8');
gs.info(typeof incGR.variables);
gs.info(incGR.variables ? true : false);
gs.info(incGR.variables.location);
gs.info(incGR.variables.constructor.name);
```

When run as a background script, it prints the following:

```
*** Script: object
*** Script: false
*** Script: 8269b993db7d3200860930cf9d961945
*** Script: GlideElementVariables
```

Now I understand that `incGR` and `incGR.variables` are actually Java objects (created in an old version of the Rhino engine). Still, how can `incGR.variables` be false if it is a non-empty object?

Comment: `typeof null` is `'object'`.

Comment: @Unmitigated If an object is null then obviously it is false. But this is not null, and yet it is still false.

Comment: What happens if you put a second `gs.info(incGR.variables ? true : false);` after the first? On the face of it the property lookup is not always returning the same value. BTW, `null` is not an object in JavaScript, it's has its own data type, "null". (`typeof` is so entrenched it can't be corrected).

Comment: Trying `gs.info(incGR.variables === null)` first off could also be revealing.

Comment: `gs.info(incGR.variables === null)` prints `false`.  The behavior is consistent regardless of the order of the statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worth pointing out several things:

#### We classify Booleans in JS into "truthy" and "falsy"

Truthy means it will cause an `if` or `?` to be used; falsy means it will go to the `else` or `:`.

So in this statement of yours:

> Thus, any JavaScript object must be true unless it is null.

I think you meant:

> Thus, any JavaScript object must be truthy unless it is falsy.

But we understand what you mean, don't worry!

#### This is the puzzle you face

How can `incGR.variables ? true : false` be `false` *and yet* there be values for `incGR.variables.location` and `incGR.variables.constructor.name`?

That is indeed a puzzle to me too. I agree with you that the only way `incGR.variables.location` can have a value (in this case, a string), is for `incGR.variables` to be an object, and therefore be truthy.

#### Possible solutions

Have you checked whether it might not be a standard Javascript object? Might there be a "getter" that specifically responds with a "falsy" value for `incGR.variables` but does give proper values for `incGR.variables.location`?

You could further help debugging by adding this line:

```
gs.info(JSON.stringify(incGR.variables,null,2));
```

and reporting the result.

#### You could "launder" it to make it behave properly

Doing the following will turn it into a proper Javascript object.

```
var incGR = new GlideRecord('incident');
incGR.get('49eab040975d6510378377500153afe8');

const incGR_js = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(incGR));

gs.info(typeof incGR_js.variables);
gs.info(incGR_js.variables ? true : false);
gs.info(incGR_js.variables.location);
gs.info(incGR_js.variables.constructor.name);
```

Comment: It is definitely NOT a standard JavaScript object.

Comment: If I try to stringify it I get a bunch of values including `"location":{}`.

Comment: If I print the value of `incGR.variables.location.constructor.name` it prints `GlideElementVariable`.

Comment: "Might there be a getter that specifically responds with a falsy value?". Most likely. There is probably a "getter" somewhere in the Java code (which I cannot see) that is causing a falsy value to be returned in this particular context.

Comment: So how did you get on with the "laundering" approach?

Comment: The laundering does not work. When you `stringify` the parent object you get a bunch of empty child objects. But we know that the child objects are not really empty, because they have properties, and when you print them they have values. I guess this proves that these are not "standard" JavaScript objects. They are Rhino objects. And the standard rules do not apply.

Comment: So you may need to iterate over them to read them individually and put them into a JS object that behaves more predictably.